# Ignore Liquibase exception when file not found

Tags: liquibase

I am running one changelog file using liquibase to deploy few database objects. If a particular file in the changelog is not found, I get the File Not Found error and execution stops.
I want to ignore files which are not found instead of raising error.
I checked the documentation, but was not able to find anything for my use case.
Any leads?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my answer is kind of an opinion-based, but here it goes.

To my mind, `<changeSet id="foo" author="bar" failOnError="false">` should work.

But looking at Liquibase's source code, it seems that for some reason `failOnError` attribute is not taken into account for `<sqlFile>` change. And if there's an error during handling of provided sql file, then `UnexpectedLiquibaseException` is thrown.

Perhaps creation of your own `<customChange>` [change](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/custom_change.html) will help. Perhaps t[his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160767/6012939) could help you.