# Database migration in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, migration, liquibase

In our spring boot application I integrate liquibase for schema migration.
Even it's possible to do data migration in a single database with liquibase as  well, in some cases I need to change related data somewhere else (etc. storage), so I would need higher level abstraction.

Running scripts on on start will slow up-time, so was thinking to have separate main class in my spring boot which will run the migration code (The challenge here is to configure it to run with spring context and profiles)

Will it be good approach or anyone may suggest another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `customChange` for this purpose: [Java code changeset in liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987460/java-code-changeset-in-liquibase)

Or you call the Liquibase API from some of your custom code instead. It's not very hard to run the migrations manually.

Comment: That is huge step to solve my problems, however, is there a way to access Spring Beans?

Comment: I don't know, you will have to read into it, but I think it should be possible.